# Not able to access some websites

Tags: networking

i am having trouble in loading some website but i can see connected status in my firefox browser .i am using google dns

but i can open this site using vpn

i adding my network details.....

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1b:38:a7:6a:17  
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:8423 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:7974 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:5823300 (5.8 MB)  TX bytes:1127573 (1.1 MB)
      Interrupt:19 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:721 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:721 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:67367 (67.3 KB)  TX bytes:67367 (67.3 KB)

m         Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1b:38:a7:6a:17  
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:27 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:6347 (6.3 KB)

ppp0      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol  
      inet addr:117.213.60.155  P-t-P:117.213.56.1  Mask:255.255.255.255
      UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1492  Metric:1
      RX packets:8356 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:7810 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:3 
      RX bytes:5588296 (5.5 MB)  TX bytes:899475 (899.4 KB)
```

i tried to ping www.thehindu.com but i receive no output

```
amaljohn@amaljohn-laptop:~$ ping www.thehindu.com
```

PING www.thehindu.com (121.241.247.61) 56(84) bytes of data.

i receive no output.

when i do port scan i receive following output:

```
Port    State   Service
80/tcp  open    http
81/tcp  open    hosts2-ns
113/tcp closed  ident
```

tracerout:

```
Hop Hostname    IP  Time 1
1   117.213.60.155  117.213.60.155  0.188
1   117.213.56.1    117.213.56.1    46.290
1   117.213.56.1    117.213.56.1    46.285
2   218.248.166.10  218.248.166.10  209.502
3   115.114.130.49.STATIC-Chennai.vsnl.net.in   115.114.130.49  100.844
4   121.243.80.250.static-chennai.vsnl.net.in   121.243.80.250  101.942
5   121.241.247.61.static-chennai.vsnl.net.in   121.241.247.61  93.233
```

details of my iptables:

```
amaljohn@amaljohn-laptop:~$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Answer (score 0):

Your traceroute show that all is OK.

```
5   121.241.247.61.static-chennai.vsnl.net.in   121.241.247.61  93.233
```

But, all is OK with [traceroute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traceroute) only(UDP or ICMP). You can not ping server, than ICMP blocked, probably on the provider side. Can you ping another IP addresses?

Looks like your provider close TCP/ICMP connections to this site.

Try to trace site with different keys: -U and -I.

Port mapper show you that 80 port is Open, try to connect to server via telnet on this port:

```
# telnet 121.241.247.61 80
```

Try to use different browser and wget:

```
# wget -O - 121.241.247.61:80
```

You can always use [Tor](http://torproject.org) to bypass such restrictions of extermelly ugly providers.